# How do I run an Eclipse project on my local machine using the Weblogic Eclipse server?

Tags: java, localhost, weblogic12c, eclipse-oxygen

I have set up the Weblogic Server 12c R2(12.2.1.3) in Eclipse Oxygen 3.
I am trying to run the project on my localhost. The Server shows as started, however my local is not connecting? I have searched for an answer for almost a day, but have not found an answer yet - your help will be greatly appreciated:)

Attached is a snapshot of the Eclipse connected to the weblogic and my local not connecting.

[Eclipse + localhost path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiDYz.png)

Comment: What's the response if you require your server API? To make sure your server is really starting, you could check if the port is already in use.

Comment: The response is 404-not found. When I check the port on CMD it shows LISTENING & ESTABLISHED!